# How to make markdown post a link to a website?

Tags: github, markdown

So I'm making a portfolio website. The code is in markdown and hosted within a github repository:

```
---
title: Heart Failure Survival Analysis
description: An R project to explore Patient Survival Data.
image: /assets/images/heart_beat.jpg
layout: page
---

This is text that would show if you click on the current post.
```

What I would like to happen is, instead of having a post within my website populate, have the user be linked to another website altogether.

How would I do that? I have a feeling it has to do with changing `layout: page` but I am so unfamiliar with markdown.

Thank You.

Comment: you want a link on your website's front page? then edit the layout file... perhaps it's called layouts/page.rb or something... are you using github pages or what?